# How to use mysqli query instead of mysql_query without getting FATAL ERROR?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have change the mysql_query statement to mysqli as below

```
 $sqlordlod = "SELECT * FROM order_list 
          WHERE user_id = '$user_id' 
          ORDER by order_id LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit ";
 $result = $mysqli->query($sqlordlod);
 $countrw = $result->num_rows;
 echo $countrw;
```

DB connection file

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
```

Anyway, follow to the suggestions I have made the above modifications, but got:

> Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_/globe/ru/profile.php on line 487
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_/globe/ru/profile.php on line 487

Below is line 487

```
while($rowld = $mysqli->query($result)->fetch_array())
{
// flip flop controling the tr class to change the color
if ($classchk ==3){
        $classchk =1;
    }
if ($classchk ==2){
  $classname = "alt";
}else{
  $classname = "none";

    }
```

Comment: Could you provide more code so i can understand what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

[num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) is a property, not a method:

```
$countrw = $result->num_rows;
                            ^--- no function call
```

Comment: no. it's not a method. it's a PROPERTY of the mysqli statement object.

Answer (score 1):

num_rows is a property not a method.

```
$sqlordlod = "SELECT * FROM order_list 
              WHERE user_id = '$user_id' 
              ORDER by order_id LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit ";
$result = $mysqli->query($sqlordlod);
$countrw = $result->num_rows;
echo $countrw;
```

Edit: something is really wrong with your code. I guess you would like to do the following:

```
while($rowld = $result->fetch_array())
{
// flip flop controling the tr class to change the color
if ($classchk ==3){
        $classchk =1;
    }
if ($classchk ==2){
  $classname = "alt";
}else{
  $classname = "none";

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your correction but got new errors, I have modified the questions and saved the error messages in the question body a long with the code. kindly have a look at the post again, before being down voted again for no reason :D thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $result = $mysqli->query($sqlordlod);
```

with

```
$result = $mysqli->query($serverconnection,$sqlordlod);
```

Here $serverconnection is your db connection result

try this one

here is the easy and working code for counting the rows

```
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbusername="root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname="test";

$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);

/* check connection */
$sqlordlod = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
//$resultordlod = mysql_query($sqlordlod);
//$countrw = mysql_num_rows($resultordlod);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlordlod);
// fetch the result row.
$countrw = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $countrw;
```

Comment: I have added the db connection script to the question, please have a look at that. And I have changed the query to $result = $mysqli->query($mysqli,$sqlordlod);  is that what you mean? if yes then I got a new error Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Applications/xamppfiles/h....../prole.php on line 461

Comment: please write the 461 line here

Comment: -1. mysqli in object mode does not require a connection handle, because that handle is built into the object. In fact, your method call is outright WRONG because there **IS NO PARAMTER TO PASS THE HANDLE**

Comment: For which point you are saying it ... because if we remove the $con from the mysqli_query .... it will return an error that is "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given" so we have to use the connection string i think